# Upperbound for quadratic recurrence equation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I have a quadratic recurrence equation $\forall n \ge 2$ of the form

$$
f(n)=\sum_{l=1}^{n-1} f(l)f(n-l),
$$

with the initial condition $f(1) =1$. The first few terms of the series are given by

> 1, 1, 2, 5, 14, 42, 132, 429, 1430, 4862, 16796, 58786, 208012, 742900, ...

I am interested in an upper bound for this equation. By means of trial and error (up to 10k terms) it turns out that the following upper bound works
$$
f(n) < 2^{2n}.
$$

How can one proof that this upper bound is indeed true for all $n$?

Comment: [Important sequence!](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C2%2C5%2C14%2C42&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: Thanks! Did not know that site, it is brilliant! And indeed the upper bound was true, the relation grows asymptotically towards $4^n/(\sqrt{\pi}n^{3/2})$.

Comment: You are welcome.  You may want to look at the less condensed (but much less comprehensive)  Wikipedia article on Catalan numbers.

Comment: I have seen it now, did not know that this recurrence relation existed in the first place. Now that I know it's name I can look up much more interesting facts about this relation :).